# Find exact match from Array

Tags: java

In java I want to iterate an array to find any matching words from my input string

if the input string is appended to numbers it should return true.

```
Array arr = {"card","creditcard","debitcard"}
String inputStr = "need to discard pin" --> Return False
String inputStr = "need to 444card pin" --> Return True if its followed by number
```

I tried the below code, but it returns `true` as it takes "card" from the "discard" string and compares, but I need to do an exact match

`Arrays.stream(arr).anymatch(inputString::contains)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with most answers here is that they do not take punctuation into consideration. To solve this, you could use a regular expression like below.

```java
String[] arr = { "card", "creditcard", "debitcard" };
String inputStr = "You need to discard Pin Card.";

Arrays.stream(arr)
    .anyMatch(word -> Pattern
        .compile("(?<![a-z-])" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?![a-z-])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        .matcher(inputStr)
        .find());
```

- With `Pattern.quote(word)`, we escape any character within each word with is a special character in the context of a regular expression. For instance, the literal string `a^b` would never match, because `^` means the start of a string if used in a regular expression.
- `(?<![a-z-])` and `(?![a-z-])` mean that there is not a *word character* immediately preceding or succeeding the word. For instance, *`discard`* will not match, even if it contains the word *`card`*. I have used only lowercase in these character classes because of the next bullet:
- The flag `CASE_INSENSITIVE` passed to the `compile` method causes the pattern to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/n05aT6)

Comment: String.split() supports regular expressions.

Comment: i have another scenario if the input string has match string followed by numbers it should return true. String inputStr = "need to 324card pin"; --> Need to return true, as it has numbers

Comment: @Sadu Are you sure? [I created an online demo](https://ideone.com/nef4Vn), where it actually works.

Comment: @MC Emperor, sorry , your logic works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @MC Emperor : punctuation into consideration ? i don't understand your context, please give some example.

Comment: @Sadu Suppose your sentence is `You need to insert your card.`. If we run some code from the other answers, `List<String> wordsToBeChecked = Arrays.asList(inputStr.split("[ 0-9]"));
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(wordsToBeChecked::contains));`, then it will print `false`, even while the word "card" is contained within the sentence.

Comment: @MCEmperor : got it, i agree on your logic.. Thanks for helping with perfect solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234187/discussion-between-sadu-and-mc-emperor).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```java
String[] arr = {"card","creditcard","debitcard"}; // array that keeps the words
String inputStr = "need to discard pin"; // String that keeps the 'sentence'

String[] wordsToBeChecked = inputStr.split(" "); // We take the string and split it at each " " (space) 

HashSet<String> matchingWords = new HashSet<>(); // This will keep the matching words

for (String s : arr) 
{
    for (String s1 : wordsToBeChecked) 
    {
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) // If first word matches with the second
        {
            matchingWords.add(s1); // add it to our container
        }
    }
}
```

Or using Java 8 `Streams`:

```java
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(arr);
List<String> sentenceWordList = Arrays.asList(inputStr.split(" "));

List<String> matchedWords = wordList.stream().filter(sentenceWordList::contains)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this does not address the scenario of the 444card as seen in example above though?

Comment: @YHStan the OP has changed the original question, it was not there when I answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string using a regular expression

```
String[] arr = {"card","creditcard","debitcard"};
String inputStr = "need to discard pin";

List<String> wordsToBeChecked = Arrays.asList(inputStr.split("[ 0-9]"));

Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(wordsToBeChecked::contains);
```

If your word list and input string is longer, consider splitting your input string into a hashset. Looksups will be faster, then:

```
Set<String> wordsToBeChecked = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(inputStr.split(" ")));
```

Comment: i have another scenario if the input string has match string followed by numbers it should return true.

String inputStr = "need to 324card pin";  --> Need to return true, as it has numbers

Comment: @sadu, try this: `inputStr.split("[ 0-9]")`. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```java
String[] arr = {"card","creditcard","debitcard"};
String inputStr = "need to discard pin";
var contains = Arrays.stream(inputStr.split(" ")).anyMatch(word -> Arrays.asList(arr).contains(word));
```

You can adjust the split regex to include all kinds of whitespace too.

Also: Consider an appropriate data structure for lookups. Array will be `O(n)`, `HashSet` will be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Set of the words in `inputStr` and then check the words list against that Set.

```
Set<String> inputWords = uniqueWords(inputStr);
List<String> matchedWords = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .anyMatch(word -> inputWords.contains(word))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Building the Set may be non-trivial if you have to account for hyphenation, numbers, punctuation, and so forth.  I'll wave my hands and ignore that - here's a naive implementation of uniqueWords(String) that assumes they are separated by spaces.

```
public Set<String> uniqueWords(String string) {
  return Arrays.stream(string.split(" "))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```